# Reading files in exported rcp eclipse product

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, static-files

I am developing an Eclipse RCP application and in some cases I need to read some template files where I have stored inside some of the bundles.

I tried many approaches and they work ok when executing the code but without sucess when I export the product since probably the bundles are exported as jars and it cannot access the stored folders/files...

I tried both approaches suggested here:
http://www.vogella.com/blog/2010/07/06/reading-resources-from-plugin/

Also it will be much easier if I could see these errors before exporting the product if you have any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem was that I didn't select the folder with the files in the manifest.mf for the build.

But it was really confusing because code runs when not exported which means it doesnt use  the build configuration for the plugin.

http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t115424.html